# How to show checkmark and move button at a same time in a UITableViewCell

Tags: iphone, uitableview, move, checkmark

How can I show checkmark accessory and move accessory at a same time in a UITableViewCell, maybe the checkmark on the left and move button on the right of cell. I need it because I want to let user chose to enable/disable options and also reorder them.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

its really unfortunate that ios has no such kind of checkmark accessories so you have to make it programmatically....i have sample code where i have made a view and set an "right" image for showing that...if someone click on that view then this "right" image will set visible neither it will be hidden....when someone click on the view then using gestureRecognizer i got the touch event.....now there is another question is, you want a movable accessory so that you can set animation on that view. i hope you have got me...